# QT emitting signal on screensaver (windows)

Tags: c++, qt, qevent, windows-screensaver

Is there a way in QT to detect when the system is entering screensaver (in windows)?
keep in mind, that my process is a background process and isn't active all the time, so i can't use this as an Qevent... and i don't want to try and figure out if the user hasn't touched the keyboard or mouse for x time, only to detect if the pc has opened the screen saver... any ideas?

Comment: Are you using QCoreApplication (or a subclass)?

Comment: You can see http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15604 . But it only detects it when the application is in foreground. Maybe you can have another application in foreground to just detect screen saver and notify your main application. This second application could be launched using `QProcess`.